# creating an "elevated button" effect in android

Tags: android, button

I want the button to appear as though it has space in between the bottom of it's face and the canvas. Then, when clicked, it will appear as though there is no space between the button and the canvas. I know I can style the button with xml to give it those 2 looks but I don't know how to do the elevated look.

My question is how would one go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or something of what you want? Are you looking for a beveled effect?

Comment: I added something like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yeah, you can make that easily with Photoshop or something similar. You just make the two states you want and use a selector file. I can't tell you an easy way strictly through Java.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I better learn Photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest approach to this is creating 2 background images, each fitting the state you want, then you can either set the backgrounds according the button's state, or change the backgrounds by setting an onTouchListener to the button.

Comment: Thanks! That was the idea I had, just needed to make sure I had to create my own buttons.